# Android Studio: "Cannot perform refactoring. This element cannot be renamed"

Tags: android

I would like to change the name of the graphics, but android studio shows an error:

*"Cannot perform the refactoring. This element cannot be renamed"*

On the left is a tutorial on where it works, and on the right my code
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        style="@style/NameStyle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Refactor works only in the `id` window:

[image]

Why doesn't it work in XML code?

This is the first project on Kubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to rename a built in drawable of the android platform while the tutorial screenshot you posted is trying to rename the id of the view

What I mean is

The resources having the `@android:` as prefix are the ones that are built in the android platform and thus can't be refactored or renamed and your screenshot is trying to rename like so. You can see the dialog title `Rename xyz and its occurence to` which indicates what element you are trying to rename

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView" // This is being changed in the screenshot
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" // You are trying to change this
```